# Create progress bar or milestone type graphs in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to display project progress in Excel 2007. Is there a way to show a progress bar like graph filled for completed percentage and empty until end date for a milestone or the whole project? It seems I cannot find this functionality.

I used conditional formatting to get the following, but am not satisfied:

[image: conditional formatting version]

The number stands for percentage.

I made another example where the number now stands for the completed percentage of a project. If a milestone is passed it should be colored. Milestones should be passed on a certain date or period.

[image: milestone version]

Comment: Just trying to clarify your question, you are happy with the data bar type of conditional formatting where the cell is a task and has a percentage complete. What you would like to do though is change the conditional formatting for a milestone to go from no fill before the milestone to all filled once the milestone has passed? If I'm correct with this, can you clarify what the number in the milestone cell represents?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to provide a condition for when the conditional formatting will trigger?  If I understand you correctly you do not want to show a progress bar for M6, M7 or M8 because those dates haven't passed yet?

Try this:  http://superuser.com/questions/445968/excel-conditional-formatting-multiple-data-bars-and-data-icons-in-one-cell

Answer (score 1):

You could get really hacky with this and use sparkline columns.

Here's how you'd structure your sheet:

[image]

Column `E` is where you enter the completion % for each milestone. Column `C` simply has references to column `E` with conditional formatting applied to them to show just the icons.

In cell `F2`, enter `=IF($E2>=F$1,1,0)`, then drag down and right to cell `Y10` (alternatively, select from `F2` to `Y10` and hit `Ctrl`+`D` and `Ctrl`+`R`).

This creates a table of ones and zeroes for completion at those steps. You can get as granular as you want with this table, but I figured steps of 5 would suffice.

With `F2:Y10` selected, go to Insert > Column (in the Sparklines group in the ribbon), or type `Alt` `N` `S` `O`. Pick the empty slot in column `D` (`D2:D9`) as your location range. Resize column `D` to make it look like a progress bar:

[image]

Next I'd either hide or group columns `F:Y` or change their number format to `;;;` so as to hide their value. If you choose to hide or group the columns, you will need to change the sparkline settings for Hidden and Empty Cells (click on the sparklines, then `Alt` `J` `D` `D` `H`). You will also probably want to set the minimum and maximum axis values (`Alt` `J` `D` `A` then `C` or `V`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a text representation and you have your % value in cell A1, you can use:

`=REPT(".",A1*50)&TEXT(A1,"0%")&REPT(".",(1-A1)*50)`

This will give you results like:

```
0%..................................................
.....10%.............................................
..........20%........................................
...............30%...................................
....................40%..............................
.........................50%.........................
..............................60%....................
...................................70%...............
........................................80%.........
.............................................90%....
..................................................100%
```

You can change the hard-coded value of 50 lower/higher to give less/more granularity.

You'll get best results using a fixed width font.

Comment: I tried this. Am note sure but thx anyway.